# How to defer/delay execution of applied gradle script to the last of build script

Tags: gradle, build

I've a Gradle build script which is like this:

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: java
apply from: some-other-script.gradle


project.ext {
   distDir = "${xxx}"
   buildDir = "${yyy}"
   testLibDir = "${zzzz}"
   webArtifactFile = "directory/aaaa.war"
}

//code to clean, build code. etc.
```

and the other script have:

`some-other-script.gradle`

```
//code to perform some common-tasks;
//Here I want to access the property exported by build.gradle

//like:
def file = webArtifactFile;

some code for that file.
```

But as I've applied `some-other-script.gradle` on top I am unable to get properties exported by `build.gradle file`

But If I `apply from: some-other-build-script.gradle` at the end of `build.gradle` like:

```
apply plugin: java


project.ext {
   distDir = "${xxx}"
   buildDir = "${yyy}"
   testLibDir = "${zzzz}"
   webArtifactFile = "directory/aaaa.war"
}

//code to clean, build code. etc.

 apply from: some-other-script.gradle
```

Then I'm able to access all the properties exported in build script (but this makes code un-readable).

So my question is:

How Can I delay/defer execution of applied Gradle script to the last of build script?

PS. I'm very new to gradle so this may come as very insane question to experts but still I'm seeking help for this one.

Hope experts here will help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:project_evaluation) : *Project evaluation listener* can be used in your case.

You have two options:

1) apply your script plugin within a `afterEvaluate` listener in your main `build.gradle` script:

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: java
afterEvaluate {
    //  some-other-script.gradle  script will have access to properties exported by main build script
    apply from: some-other-script.gradle
}
```

2) implement the `afterEvaluate` listener logic in the script plugin itself:

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: java
apply from: some-other-script.gradle
```

*some-other-script.gradle*

```
afterEvaluate {
    def file = webArtifactFile;

    // some code for that file.
}
```

Solution 2 is maybe better as it will keep your main `build.gradle` cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Mate! You saved me :).